# why are there draw rate and update rate in fixed time step game loop?

Tags: java, game-loop, fixed-timestep

http://www.gameprogblog.com/generic-game-loop/

Java

```
boolean onLoop( Game game, GameState state, GameInput input, Graphics2D gr ) {
  long nanosElapsed = state.tick();
  updateTime += nanosElapsed;
  int updateCount = 0;
  while (updateTime >= updateRate && updateCount < maxUpdates) {
    game.input( input );
    input.clear();
    if (!game.isPlaying()) {
      return false;
    }
    state.update();
    game.update( state );
    if (!game.isPlaying()) {
      return false;
    }
    updateCount++;
    updateTime -= updateRate;
  }
  drawTime += nanosElapsed;
  int drawCount = 0;
  if (drawTime >= drawRate || updateCount > 0) {
    state.interpolate = getStateInterpolation();
    state.forward = state.interpolate * state.seconds;
    state.backward = state.forward - state.seconds;
    state.draw();
    game.draw( state, gr );
    drawCount++;
    drawTime -= (drawRate == 0 ? drawTime : drawRate);
  }
  if (sleep && drawCount == 0 && updateCount == 0) {
    long actualTime = updateTime + state.getElapsedSinceTick();
    long sleep = (updateRate - actualTime) / 1000000L;
    if (sleep > 1) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep( sleep - 1 );
      } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
  }
  return (drawCount > 0);
}
```

I am a beginner in game programming. I wanted to know when using fixed time step why do we have different update rates and draw rates. I have seen this in more than just the above code and if i plan to make a 30 fps game then what is a reasonable draw rate to have to match 30 fps update rate?. Can you explain in understandable terms? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Optimization and consistency

Comment: The article you linked explains everything very clearly, perhaps you should reread that, or ask for clarification on what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

The short version is that there can be a huge variation in frame rate due to a myriad of factors, many outside of the game's control.  These variations can cause a lot of bugs and other gameplay oddities, especially in physics.  Using a fixed timestep for updates avoids bugs.